# Asp.net MVC Session state Overlap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a website created by ASP.Net MVC, and I use the session to keep the users logged in.  In this case, when logging in a multi tabs with different users, previous sessions are erased and only the last one will remain.  How can I access the application to log in from several browser using Server?

Comment: Please clarify "when logging in a multi tabs with different users". One browser with 2 or more tabs, a different user for each tab? Have you googled how session ID's per browser or per tab are handled with one, two and more tabs are handled?

Answer (score 0):

By default, session should exist one per server, which will be shared across multiple tabs (unless using tricks like File > New Session in IE, etc.).  By default this shouldn't be happening, so we'll need to see some code around how you are managing your session to solve this.